# How to make the divider animate when switching tabs iOS material by cosmic mind

Tags: ios, cosmicmind

How do I animate the divider so that the divider on top of the TabBar slides left or right depending on the tab I'm currently on? I have looked at the sample application but it doesn't have a sliding Divider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the `TabsController`. You can find a sample here: [TabsController Sample](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Samples/tree/master/Projects/Programmatic/TabsController). [image]

Comment: How? Currently all I have is a divider over the whole tab bar. Im also using the code: isMotionEnabled = true and motionTabBarTransitionType = .autoReverse(presenting: .pull(direction: .left)) In order to slide the screen when tabs switch. Ive set my tab controller to the class BottomNavigationController as well.. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You need to use the TabsController, which is different from the TabBarController. The TabsController is the custom one made by CosmicMind, the TabBarController is a subclass of UITabBarController.

Comment: I did use tabsController now, however my UITabBarController does not recognize TabsController as an appropriate custom class...

Comment: The UITabBarController has nothing to do with TabsController. They are completely separate. Please refer to the sample.